Are there promising scientific research avenues that could ultimately help resolve the debate on the nature of the mind?
The nature of the mind and its relationship to the body remains a central topic of debate in the philosophy of mind, as evidenced by overview articles such as:

Wikipedia: Mind–body problem
Britannica: Mind-body problem
Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy: Dualism and Mind
Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy: Dualism
Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy: The Mind/Brain Identity Theory

Rather than leaving the issue to endless philosophical debate, are there promising scientific research avenues that could potentially help resolve this enduring question?
In other words, could the mind-body problem be more effectively approached through science than philosophy?

Yes, that's what scientists do. They are not waiting on philosophy. All science is promising. It just may take another 500 years. That's no less promising though

Well, dualism is unfalsifiable, so no. They can maintain that dualism is true no matter how well we manage to explain how the brain works and linking consciousness to that. And neuroscience is trucking along on the journey of explaining that. So... yes? The mind-body problem is approached more effectively through science than philosophy, given all the results science has already delivered in that area.

Philosophy by itself has never resolved any debate on any matter in the world. Only science has. Yes, the scientific method is a philosophy technically, but the point is that merely thinking about something never gets you anywhere.
Once those thoughts turn into experiments, it becomes science. Can you name one matter that was ever resolved by pure thought and without empiricism? (barring trivial things such as 2+2 not being 5).

No, because neuroscientists don't see a problem here.  From a neuroscience perspective, your mind is so much grey and white matter and electrical potentials and chemical gradients, and this has been a consensus for many, many years.  Anyone who is still asking in 2024 "when will science solve this problem?" doesn't actually want the solution that science is putting forward.

@Him So what do you make of the whole field of philosophy of mind? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mind

@user80226 it is worth noting that the mind/body problem predates rigorous scientific method and neuroscience specifically by literally millenia.  So, the corpus of work identifying mind/body duality as a problem before we were able to even begin to quantify such things is absolutely enormous.  Still, at 40, I have not been alive at a time when neuroscientists weren't almost universally satisfied as to the answer to the mind/body question.

SEP, Philosophy of Neuroscience discusses much of the relevant research and its philosophical significance.
